# How to concurrently iterate through an sql result set in Golang?

Tags: go

The next() method is sequential, is there a way to concurrently iterate through the loop?

I have a result set of 200k rows that I am looping through sequentially and doing logic on each row and want to split it up.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. Unless you're doing some ordering it will not be possible. A set or in this case a table is a collection of unordered items. In order to do this concurrently you'll have to be able to split your collection into sub sets and process each individually in their own goroutine aggregating the results in the calling scope. You want to take a divide and conquer approach and express that in an algorithm. If you can provide more details about the data I could help suggest how you might get the subsets and process them.

Comment: To expand on that, firstly I would be making a decision of whether or not I'm getting the results in one query. Say you're getting users out of a database, you could for example use a where clause to divide get your current 200k result set in 5 different queries, each being made from their own goroutine doing the processing ect. Alternately you could get all the results at once then use subslicing to divide the results right as you pass them into the process method that you're calling in a goroutine. Hope that helps! I'll provide an answer if you get something more concrete here.

Answer (score 9):

The sql.Rows you get back from your query can't be used concurrently (I believe).

but you can do most of the heavy lifting in goroutines.

Here is an example (non-working, but close), on [Play](http://play.golang.org/p/dwxL-D0yzJ)

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "sql"

type Row struct {
    x string
    y string
    z string
}

func processor(ch chan Row) {
    for row := range <-ch {
        // be awesome
    }
}
func main() {
    ch := make(chan Row)
    // two handler go routines (current processors)
    go processor(ch)
    go processor(ch)
    rows := db.Query("select x,y,z from whatever")
    for rows.Next() {
        var row Row
        if err := rows.Scan(&row.x, &row.y, &row.z); err != nil {
            // do something with error
        } else {
            ch <- row
        }
    }
}
```